# EndpointNotFoundException [in Windows Mobile 6.5.3 APP]

Tags: c#, wcf, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

Brief summary of the "problem":

I have created a host according to these instructions: [LINK](http://bebugsblog.blogspot.de/2010/01/wcf-tutorial-1.html); and then according to [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sry_143/using-wcf-in-windows-mobile-application/) instruction for a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 application i created the classes for the connection (via NetCFSvcUtil).

Now it is so that I get the following error message (if I "get" me want data):

**Error message:**

```
    There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8500/MyService 
    that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
    address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Oddly enough (to me, in fact, inexplicable), when I go to the very same principle (this time SvcUtil) a "non Compact Framework" make application to me, I can easily query my "data".

In addition: Both times were by Tool (depending on the application one for CF and one for the "normal") created and incorporated the required classes (successful); but unfortunately only works the query in the desktop application.

Anyone has any advice?

Comment: Can you please post the inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by host and client machines are different. When you try to reach

```
http://localhost:8500/MyService
```

using svcutil, since its on the local machine, you can access. But when you try to access using Emulator or phone, it tries to reach its own ip adress.

How will you solve:

Install IIS and setup a site containing that service.
Reference to your computer ip adress instead of localhost from client.